# pure c++ and winapi trapping messages of 3rd party application

Tags: c++, winapi, window, hook

I need to open 3rd party application like for example Adobe Reader. I do it like this.
    `ShellExecute(GetDesktopWindow(), "open", "test.pdf", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);`

But what I need know is to detect when user scrolls document in opened Adobe Reader. Adobe Reader is here as example, it can be for example office, excel, whatever. I tried to use hooks like this
    `hCallWndProcHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC,    winProcHookProcedure, NULL, GetThreadId(adobe));`

where adobe is handle to adobe reader. I tried to send to this handle WM_CLOSE message and adobe quit, so it is correct handle. But in winProcHookProcedure I don't detect any message, so hooks is not correctly installed on the window I think.

Is it possible to detect scrolling. Or I don't know, for example can I embeded applications like this in my window and there catch some messages? How can I do that?

What I want to do is open two same applications and when one application is scrolled, than second application is scrolled too (mirrored behaviour).

I can use only pure c++ and win32 api.

Thanks

Comment: All of the applications you named provide automation interfaces. Had you considered using them? That's what they are for.

Comment: Not very much prospect of success here

Comment: And is it possible with automation interfaces catch scrolling of that application? I saw that with automation interfaces is possible for example to move scrollbar up or down, but not to detect the scrolling. Do you have some example how can I for example detect scrolling of office document?

Comment: What you are hoping to do is not tractable.